# Vue create project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, nvm

Can anyone explain to me why I need to run `npm install -g @vue/cli` every time before creating new VUE project?
and also after installing vue/cli I am unable to create project with running `vue create project-name`. It is throwing this error > `Error: spawn yarn ENOENT` and the project is created only by this command > `vue create -m npm project-name`

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have multiple question in your post I will attempt to separate it.

### 1. Why I need to run `npm i -g @vue/cli` every time

No you don't need to. With `-g` flag it means global installation. Without `-g`, it means that the dependency only exist in the project. But global flag basically allows the dependency to be access through your entire system.

### 2. Unable to create project

With a [simple google search](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5891), users report that the issue is likely that you don't have `yarn` in your system, or some broken files, as your question lack of specification of details, please refer to the link and find a fix within the post that is most suitable for your system / case.

### Side Note:

Based on the github repo of Vue Cli,

> Vue CLI is now in maintenance mode. For new projects, please use create-vue to scaffold Vite-based projects. create-vue supports both Vue 2 and Vue 3.

you probably want to stick with Vite instead of Vue CLI unless you are maintaining legacy projects.